# Postgresql order by and limit not returning expected row

Tags: postgresql

`SELECT id, created_at FROM "location_reviews"  ORDER BY created_at DESC;`

```
 id  |     created_at
-----+---------------------
 251 | 2015-12-20 00:00:00
 426 | 2015-12-20 00:00:00
 357 | 2015-12-20 00:00:00
```

`SELECT id, created_at FROM "location_reviews"  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1;`

```
 id  |     created_at
-----+---------------------
 251 | 2015-12-20 00:00:00
```

`SELECT id, created_at FROM "location_reviews"  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;`

```
 id  |     created_at
-----+---------------------
 251 | 2015-12-20 00:00:00
```

`SELECT id, created_at FROM "location_reviews"  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2;`

```
 id  |     created_at
-----+---------------------
 357 | 2015-12-20 00:00:00
```

Why doesn't my `OFFSET 1` query return the second entry (id = 426)? Instead it returns the same row as the query with no `OFFSET`. The `created_at` column is of type `timestamp without time zone`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `created_at` has the same values in these rows. In that case you should add another field in `ORDER BY`. Otherwise the behaviour is not defined - PostgreSQL can sort them as it wants.